# $\cos(t x) \sin(x)-t \cos(x) \sin(t x)$ as $x$ goes to infinity

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Calculate $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} (\cos{t x} \sin{x}-t \cos{x} \sin{t x})$

How does one calculate the above limit?

Comment: By thinking about which term "dominates" for large $t$ and deciding how that term behaves.

Comment: @pjs36 But we're not letting $t$ become large as I see it, it's $x$ that gets big. Rather, $t$ seems to be a fixed number.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I wasn't paying close enough attention :)

Comment: When $|t| = 1$, the function is identically $0$. I doubt that the limit converges for any other value of $t$.

Comment: How can we show that it doesn't converge for other values of $t$ then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$f(x,t)=\cos(t x) \sin(x)-t \cos(x) \sin(t x)$$

When $|t|=1$ as Pual Sinclair commented $f(x,t)=f(x,1) \equiv0$ and so 
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x,1)=0$$

Assume now $|t|\ne1$. If the limit as $x\to\infty$ exists then the same limits holds for $x=\pi n$ as $n\to\infty$, however
$$f(\pi n,t)=(-1)^{n+1} t \sin \pi  n t$$
which is oscilating as $n\to\infty$ for $t\notin \mathbb{Z}$ (it's vanishes $t\in \mathbb{Z}$, but this is doesn't help with $x$).
Thus
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x,t)=\text{D.N.E.}$$